# Nudists at the window?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the Mishna (Ohalot 11:4), we learn of a disagreement between the schools of Shammai and of Hillel, concerning a person who is leaning out of a window while a funeral procession walks beneath them on the street below. According to the school of Hillel, this person functions as a tent and transmits the impurity into the house (since people, acc. to the school of Hillel, are to be viewed as hollow), while the school of Shammai holds that they do not function as a tent and do not convey the impurity into the house.

According to this mishna, there are two situations in which the schools of Hillel and of Shammai agree with one another: if the person is wearing clothes, or if there are two people, one on top of the other ("ומודים שאם היה לבוש בכליו או שהיו שנים זה על גבי זה").

Let me read that again. They agree with one another if the person is wearing clothes **OR** if there are two people, one on top of the other.

My question is: what are these two people doing on top of one another if they are not wearing clothes?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: While the answer may be obvious, it is not "lashon naki" so I will not go further with it.

Comment: ...which also raises the question--why would Hillel or Shammai let them attend classes without clothes?

Answer (score 2):

There is a mishna earlier in Oholos that says:

> ט,ט  הייתה ממלאה את כל הבית, ואין בינה לבין הקורות פותח טפח--טומאה בתוכה, הבית טמא.
> If they filled the whole house, and there isn't space in the rafters of a opening of a tephach, the house is tamei.

Here we have a contradiction between mishnayos - if a person is considered hollow enough to be an "opening of a tephach," how can it be that filling the house with people would convey tumah?

This actually relates to an question in maseches nazir:

> א,ה  הריני נזיר מלוא הבית, או מלוא הקופה--בודקין אותו
>
> [One who says] "I am a nazir, FILL THE HOUSE!" [We] Check it.

The command to fill the house or basket by the nazir is a statement that he will be a nazir according to the number of people who physically fit into that enclosed space. This declaration was [very common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonebooth_stuffing) among teenagers and [clowns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clown_car), which explains why so many of them have long, unkempt hair.

As you can clearly see in photos, the upper halves of the stacked people often project outside of the phone-booth, this explains our question - their upper bodies are sticking out the window in an attempt to cram as many people into the house as possible.